# Is autoinstall compatible only with Ubuntu server installer? Can it be used to deploy desktop environment?

Tags: server, 20.04

I would like to make Ubuntu 20.04 installation automatic to easily deploy the system on target hardware. It looks that autoinstall would be a good solution, but it seems that it is compatible only with server installer. However, I need a desktop environment and other desktop tools like the browser etc. Is it a good solution to base on the server installer and then add desktop environment? Will autoinstall also handle that for me?

Comment: take a look at this question/Answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233454/how-to-preseed-ubuntu-20-04-desktop

Comment: Thanks. It seems that the best option is to use Ubuntu Server and autoinstall. However, it is seems that Ubuntu 20.04 Desktop can be still automatized using preseed. What about the future releases then? Will they follow the server version and move to autoinstall?